# nodejs + express automatic redirection when user hits different url

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've made a bulletin board using nodejs and ejs, and deployed on heroku.
My problem is, that when the website is opened, (Ex: https://cool-plains-2948.herokuapp.com/) nothing shows up because the bulletin board only shows up when the url is /posts.

Is there anyway to redirect automatically to /posts when the website is opened or when the user mistakenly hit other urls?

I know how to do that in angularjs using $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); 
but is there a way to do on the back-end side? using nodejs?

edit: what I did and it worked:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.url === '/') {
    res.redirect('/posts');
  }
});//redirection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use * that match all path

```
app.use("*", function(req, res, next) {
    var path = req.path; // just example how it can be done

    if (path === "/") {
       // ...
       path = "/post";
    }

});
```